# Java code: change value of variable

Tags: java, android

so i have a very basic question. What my code does basically is this

User checks a RADIO BUTTON to choose a time (they have 1 hour, 2 and 3), and then click on a button from Activity1, they are then taken to Activity2 where it has a TextView that shows the time ticking down in seconds

I hope that part was clear

Now, the TextView in Activity2 should show the time passing from Activity1 by passing time in this line from Activity1

> intent.putExtra ( "Time",  time);

Whenever I try this code, the result I get is always 0 as if it isn't changing the value of *time* according to my *if statement* I have included inside each isChecked radioButton block. So, help? I know there must be a very basic and easy solution.

Thank you.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.release_bicycle);
        one = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.oneHour);
        two = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.twoHours);
        three = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.threeHours);
        Go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.releaseBTN);


        Go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {           
        @Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{

    //start bluetooth

        if (one.isChecked()) 
        {
            new CountDownTimer(3600000, 1000) 
            {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
                {   
                     time = (millisUntilFinished/1000);
                }

                public void onFinish()
                {
                    ... database
                }
            }.start();

        }


        if (two.isChecked()) 
        {
                  ...
        }


        if (three.isChecked()) 
        {           
            ...

        }


        Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, destination.class);
        intent.putExtra ( "Time",  time);
        startActivity(intent);      
    }

    });


}
```

Comment: I take it the value of `time` at this line: `intent.putExtra ( "Time",  time);` is 0?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke yes

Comment: why don't you start the countdown timer in Activity2 ?

Comment: @njzk2 because that's how my app is designed. Isn't there a way to change my time value according to my if statement?

Comment: where is the putExtra line situated?

Comment: @njzk2 as you can see in the code I just wrote, right after my *if statements* and before closing my onClick method.

Comment: @Issy probably the variable `time` hasn't been affected because `onTick` has not been called before your `onCreate` has ended. Try printing logs or add Breakpoints in your code to see what happens first

Comment: When you call `start()` it doesn't mean that `onTick` is gonna be called immediatly. `time` is being changed from another thread. You have no guarantee that `onTick` is gonna be called before `startActivity`.

Comment: @Issy : I don't see that in your code, but that does explain why `time` is not updated. `onTick` is scheduled to be executed on the main thread. (i.e.. after onClick is completed)

Comment: @Tulio : not quite right, onTick is called on the same thread as start().

Comment: @Tulio I've edited my question (check the code) my onTick is in my onCreate(). Even if this is the case, onTick is still going to be called on the same time as onCreate()?

Comment: @Issy As njzk2 said, `onTick` is scheduled to be executed. It's nothing to do with `onCreate`. I think the best solution is to change your mindset about this and maybe start `CountDownTimer` on `destination` activity. If you really need to make it works the way it is and you need just the first value of `time`, just call `time = (3600000/1000);` inside the if statement before 'new CountDownTimer()`, but that would be a dirty solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)` appears to be called after your `onCreate()` is over.

you should place the following code in your onStart for example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, destination.class);
intent.putExtra ( "Time",  time);
startActivity(intent);
```

It's a strange approach to create an activity that just starts another activity onStart or even on Create.

Another option you can do is do that code execute after a delay using a handler.

Comment: That code IS in my onCeate(), I didn't paste the entire code.